# What do I do about nematodes (roundworms) in aquascape?

Tags: aquarium, fish, safety, pest-control

I have 10 gallon (38 liters) tank aquascape, no fish yet, I noticed around 20 nematodes swimming around, can I just put platy fish and shrimp there? How do I get rid of the nematodes?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to get rid of them? Almost any fish will eat them, you'll still have them in the tank, likely in the substrate and any detritus that builds up, but it's unlikely they are harmful to anything so shouldn't be a huge concern.